# Php calendar by month

Tags: php

I have look at 100 calendar code and thkink there is no good one. So i came up with my own code, but need som help to understans what i am missing. Thinking now that i mixed up the loops or somthing have try this for a while but cant get it right. The result i getting now is in a line from top to bottom. The  dont seem to work. Can somone help me understand what i need to do?

```
<table border="1">
<?php

//counter array
$counter = 0;
//start days array
$list=array();
//current day
$curDay = date("28", $today);
// mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") , date("Y"));
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), '28', date("Y"));
// curent month
$curentmonth = '09';
// curent year
$year = 2018;
// curent month
$month = date('m');

//loop number of days in month and list them in the array
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{

    $datetime=mktime(12, 0, 0, $curentmonth, $d, $year);          
    if (date('m', $datetime)==$curentmonth)     
    $list[]=date('d', $datetime);
//try to get the right 7 weeks in a month start monday    
for ($day = 1; $day <=7; $day++) {
    $datetime   = strtotime($year.'W'.$month.$day);
    echo "<tr>";
}
// make this day red
if ($curentmonth === $month && $list[$counter] === $curDay) {

echo "<td bgcolor='ff0000'>$list[$counter]</td>";
$counter++;
// all other days in the month
} elseif ($month === $curentmonth) {
echo "<td>$list[$counter]</td>";
    $counter++;

// other month   
} else {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Proper indentation would help figuring out how your nested loops work. For instance, it looks like you start out with 7 `<tr>` tags for each day. Is that your intention? Or do you only want to output a new `<tr>` in a specific circumstance?

Comment: I mixed the loops up i Think. The result i get now is Only in one line. That is what i need help with. May forgot somthing else to.

Comment: **$today** seems to be initiated after it is used . Talking about this line: **$curDay = date("28", $today);**. Please make sure to change your code to have it initated before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried coercing your code into doing what you want, but I'm afraid there are so many logical problems that it's better to just go back to the drawing board entirely.

Looking at your code, it seems what you want to accomplish is a table that displays the weeks of the current month below each other, with each week starting on monday. For table cells that don't contain a date (e.g. the month starts or ends in the middle of a week) you want to display only a space in the cell so that it is empty.

Additionally, you want to highlight the current date.

So essentially, your intended end result is something like this for today (September 30th, 2018):

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
|    |    |    |    |    | 1  | 2    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
|  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 | 8  | 9    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
| 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | *30* |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+------+
```

There are many ways to accomplish this goal. Here's one way of doing it with simple date manipulation, so that there's no need for arrays and multiple loops:

```
// the month to render and day to highlight
$today = new DateTime();

// we'll need these to check if we're at the day we need to highlight
// or if we're rendering a date that's outside $today's month
$currentDay = $today->format('j');
$currentMonth = $today->format('n');
$daysInCurrentMonth = $today->format('t');

// figure out what Monday needs to kick off our table
$date = (clone $today)->modify('first day of this month');
if ($date->format('w') != 1) {
    $date->modify('previous monday');
}

$shouldStopRendering = false;

echo '<table border="1">';
while (!$shouldStopRendering) {
    $weekDay = $date->format('w');
    $month = $date->format('n');
    $day = $date->format('j');

    // start a new table row every time we hit a Monday, note that
    // since we forced $date to be a Monday above, our table should
    // now always start with a <tr>
    if ($weekDay == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    if ($month != $currentMonth) {
        // we're either at the beginning or end of our table
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    } else if ($day == $currentDay) {
        // highlight the current date
        echo '<td bgcolor="#ff0000">' . $day . '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>' . $day . '</td>';
    }

    if ($weekDay == 0) {
        // every time we hit a Sunday, close the current table row
        echo '</tr>';

        // on a Sunday, if we've gone outside the current month **or**
        // this Sunday happens to be the last day we need to render,
        // stop looping so we can close the table
        if ($month != $currentMonth || $day == $daysInCurrentMonth) {
            $shouldStopRendering = true;
        }
    }

    // move on to the next day we need to display
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
echo '</table>';
```

Note this line:

```
$date = (clone $today)->modify('first day of this month');
```

The reason I'm cloning `$today` instead of just creating a new `DateTime` instance, is that you may wish to change `$today` to render a different month. Or maybe you're looping over a number of months to render a calendar for a whole year. I don't know which is the case, so I'm basing `$date` off of whatever `$today` happens to be.

Don't just do this:

```
$date = $today->modify('first day of this month');
```

That'll work, but it will also modify `$today` which may not be what you want if you want to re-use the current date after rendering the table.

If you're using an older version of PHP, you may not be allowed to do `(clone $today)->modify` in a single line. If that's the case, just split it up into two lines:

```
$date = clone $today;
$date->modify('first day of this month');
```

Here's a demo of this code in action (with some added whitespace for readability of the generated HTML): https://3v4l.org/Z89i8

Comment: Got error on line 12 change to $date = (clone $today->modify('first day of this month')); hard when it is not my code if i want to put in different month or year?

Comment: You misplaced a bracket. You want to perform `modify` on the result of `clone $today`, so that's the part that needs to be in brackets: `(clone $today)->modify`. The way you have it now, you're trying to clone the result of `$today->modify()` Similar to how you'd one-line object construction and calling a method: `$today_month = (new DateTime())->format('m')`;

Comment: No problem. Can you post an answer showing what you did to make it work in case future users run into a similar problem?